# ¿Como agrupar un DataTable con una columna de imagenes?

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, group-by

tengo el siguiente DataTable (ver imagen) con filas repetidas:
[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desearía poder agrupar las filas que se repiten para obtener lo siguiente. Este es mi OBJETIVO (ver imagen):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Notese que se deberan acumulan los valores de la cuarta columna "N" y la ultima columna "Total" y solo muestre una imagen de las filas repetidas, no que las fusione o reconozca si son iguales, solo que tome cualquiera de las imagenes de las filas que son repetidas por los valores de las otras columnas como la "descripción" o el "Area_parcial".

Tengo el siguiente codigo y logre agrupar las otras columnas pero cuando añado la de imagenes se complica. ¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias por su tiempo.

```
    var Tabla_agrupada = data_table_1.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(r => new
            {
                Descripción = r.Field<string>("Descripción"),
                Imagen = r.Field<Image>("Imagen"),
                UND = r.Field<string>("UND"),
                N = r.Field<int>("Nº"),
                texto = r.Field<string>("texto"),
                Area_Parcial = r.Field<double>("Area_Parcial"),
                Area_Total = r.Field<double>("Area_Total")
            })
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.Descripción, x.Imagen, x.UND, x.texto, x.Area_Parcial })
            .Select(grp => new
            {
                grp.Key.Descripción,
                grp.Key.Imagen,
                grp.Key.UND,
                N = grp.Sum(x => x.N),
                grp.Key.texto,
                grp.Key.Area_Parcial,
                Area_Total = grp.Sum(x => x.Area_Total)
            });
            DataTable nueva_tabla = data_table_1.Clone();  
            foreach (var x in Tabla_agrupada)
                nueva_tabla.Rows.Add(x.Descripción, x.Imagen, x.UND, x.N, x.texto, x.Area_Parcial, x.Area_Total);
```

Comment: Qué significa que "pero cuando añado la de imagenes se complica." qué se te complica? Qué error estás obteniendo?

Comment: @AndresGardiol Simplemente no se agrupan las filas y sigue siendo la primera tabla.

Comment: Podrías mostrar un ejemplo de cómo te quedan con el error?